# Installing KDE4 development files in 2020

Tags: linux, compiling, cmake, kde5, kde4

I want to compile the [Oxygen-transparent](https://cgit.kde.org/oxygen-transparent.git/) project which requires KDE4. I've tried building and installing the [KDELibs 4 Support](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/kdelibs4support) package , but still there's no `kde4-config` in my system.

Here's the output of running `CMake` in the Oxygen-transparent repo :

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:60 (message):
  ERROR: Could not find KDE4 kde4-config
```

Where can I find that file ? Is it possible at all to install such an old program in newer KDEs ?

By the way I use KDE Neon dev edition 5.19.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to install a theme that's only compatible with KDE 4 on a system running KDE 5 in the first place?

Comment: @Wieland I hope I can do it with KDE4 legacy support in KDE 5. But not sure if that would work with KWin. I just wanna try. And because the project isn't maintained anymore , I have to either use kubuntu trusty or just build it in bionic.

Answer (score 0):

The `kde4-config` is no longer available on the ubuntu packages website though you can download it from this [**Direct Download Link**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages.gz/trusty/man1/kde4-config.1.gz) or from this [**Ubuntu manuals link**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/kde4-config.1.html#:~:text=kde4-config%20is%20a%20command,installation%20reside%20on%20your%20system.).

You can also find some other `kde-config` files [From the ubuntu packages link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kde-config&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

I hope this helps.